# Jssor Slider Cluster error on first slide

Tags: slider, jssor

I want to implement this example http://www.jssor.com/demos/slider-cluster.html
but I have these problemms with slider 1 :

- first time displays only the first 2 slides
- After the first scroll, slider  begin with slide 2 and finish with slide 1

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It would also be helpful if you provided the code where your problem occurs.

Comment: I have not received any error message. 
The error occurs in the example site and example files

Comment: If something doesn't work it should produce error messages. Have you tried to debug the application? Have you checked for javascript errors?

Comment: Do you mean displays only the first 2 slides at the beginning?

Comment: What do you mean 'After the first scroll, slider begin with slide 2'?

Comment: Please check on your site. On first access of page page slider-cluster.html ->Slider 1 displays the first 2 pictures and then jumps to the slider 2. After running all 3 slider, slider 1 begins with picture 2